# (iOS) How to make the custom keyboard background transparent

Tags: ios, keyboard, background-color

As title, how do I make it transparent for iPad?
because it is too ugly to see gray color outside.
Thanks.

Regards,
GRTan.

Screenshot:
[image]

EDIT:
Sorry that I forgotten about the source code.
Source Code [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/3olx22bz6en5zro/CusKeyboard.zip).(UPDATED)

Comment: Seems to be a custom KeyBoard since you can't modify KeyBoard in iOS.

Comment: Yes, I used custom keyboard for my app and now i found that the background of the custom keyboard is bad (the color outside my keyboard's button) so I been surfing around the google for sometime before I posted this question. So, any help?

Comment: Depends how is coded your custom Keyboard. Without code, we can't help you. Lowing alpha to some thing (the background?) could be what you want to do.

Comment: sorry code you are provided returning a error 'This page cannot be found ' while taping that link ..

Comment: Updated download link. Sorry for just now.

Answer (score 0):

Insert following line

```
defaultLNNumberpad.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

after

```
defaultLNNumberpad = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LNNumberpad" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

in your **LNNumberpad.m** file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLQOj.png